# How to activate .vim scripts

Tags: linux, vim

There are some scripts which come supplied with .vim. What is the correct way to activate and deactivate these scripts inside vim and to make them automatically activate when vim starts up? What about scripts that are downloaded from the net?

Comment: What platform are you using Vim on? It will depend on how you set it up. iLate's answer is a good place to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Vim scripts (written in VimL, or Vimscript) are just files like any others. You could rewrite them by typing them line by line in your command line, to get the same effect.

Normally, they're *activated* by sourcing them `:source file.vim`. However, there is no general way to *deactivate them*, meaning once sourced and executed, that's it. Some plugins offer flags that will determine when the plugin is "active" or not, but that is their internal feature, not a general feature of Vimscript.

Comment: Some .vim scripts already come with vim. For these do I still have to type the full path to :source them? Is that what people do?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of a script that comes with Vim but is not active by default? The only one I know is matchit, which you activate by adding this to your `~/.vimrc`: `runtime macros/matchit.vim`

Comment: @javascriptninja - Most of those are already sourced. If you type ":scriptnames" you'll see which ones. If there is one that isn't, then yes, you have to type either the absolute or the relative path. Or use some of vim's shortcuts, $VIM, $VIMFILES, $VIMRUNTIMEPATH ...

Comment: What can I type in vim to see all the $VIM* shortcuts? What do I type to source matchit.vim?

Comment: @javascriptninja - ":echo $VIM", ":echo $VIMFILES" and so on. ":source \...path to\matchit.vim" (I'm not on my computer right now; have no idea where matchit is actually in Vim's folders)

Comment: So basically, I have to guess. I already put the full path to matchit.vim in .vimrc. I was just wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: @javascriptninja - No, wait ... what do you have to guess? Find where matchit.vim is and put something like this in your .vimrc, "source $VIM/path_to_matchit/matchit.vim". I don't know of an "easier way" (is there something complicated about this one)?

Comment: I was under the assumption that there were a lot of scripts that were not automatically activated, but if matchit.vim is the only one, then I can just put in in .vimrc and leave it there. But if lots of those scripts aren't activated by default, then there should be an easier way then having to edit .vimrc every time I want to activate one of them.

Comment: @javascriptninja - Well, there are. There are plugins like pathogen, vim-addon-manager and several others, that take some of these problems away from you. They source everything "in their path" ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to manage scripts easily, the best thing is to use Pathogen:

- https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen

It allows you to put each of the scripts into a folder and then just moving them in and out of the parent bundle folder activates / deactivates them. Take a look at the docs in the above page.